# How to filter jQuery Mobile select form dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to filter a select list by using another select list. The problem is that I cannot reload the list after its been filtered. So if a user makes a accidentally makes a wrong selection on the first list, no options will be left on the second list. You can see my code below thanks.

```
        $('#selectCftDialog').change(function() {
            //alert('Handler for .select() called.');
            var tempCftID;
            tempCftID = $("#selectCftDialog").val();
            //alert("The tempCraftID is: CftID-" + tempCraftID)
            $('#selectSpDialog option').not('#CftID-' + tempCftID).remove();    
                    });
```

Comment: Instead of removing them, detach those elements and keep them in a variable, then you can put them back using append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to save the options as `data` on the select element itself startup.

```
$('#selectSpDialog').data('options', $('#selectSpDialog option')); // Set the jquery data `options` with the initial set of options.

$('#selectCftDialog').change(function () {
    //alert('Handler for .select() called.');
    var tempCftID;
    tempCftID = $("#selectCftDialog").val();
    //alert("The tempCraftID is: CftID-" + tempCraftID)
    $('#selectSpDialog option').not('#CftID-' + tempCftID).remove(); // Ok you can remove now
});

function someEventCalledProabablyReset()
{
    var select = $('#selectSpDialog');
    select.html(select.data('options')); //Set back all the saved options.
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsEdk/)

Comment: Yep this fixed it thanks for the help. I included the reset function at the beginning of the .change event.

Comment: Hey PSL I'm encountering a bug, when the second list gets filtered you cannot select the first object in the list.

Comment: Could you please prepare a fiddle?